# Pvalue and Xquared is N/A in Box-Ljung test

Tags: r, testing, na, forecasting, p-value

```
    Box-Ljung test  
data:  <some data> 
X-squared = NA, df = 20, p-value = NA.
```

Pvalues and Xsquared are coming as N/A, but my data values doesn't have any zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have NA's in your data (Ljung Box test can't handle missing values), we will take a random example, assuming that it is a time series :

```
data <- c(12,45,48,31,12,7,78)
```

We get (setting our lag to 20) :

```
Box.test(data, lag = 20, type = "Ljung-Box", fitdf = 0)

    Box-Ljung test

data:  data
X-squared = NA, df = 20, p-value = NA
```

Kinda logical to get a NA as we are setting a lag higher than the length of our time series.

Now, we will change our lag and setting it to 1.

```
Box.test(data, lag = 1, type = "Ljung-Box", fitdf = 0)

    Box-Ljung test

data:  data
X-squared = 0.30832, df = 1, p-value = 0.5787
```

I think that your lag (20) is higher than the length of your time series (as it is here with the short example).

See `?Box.test` or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test) for more information.

Comment: Thank you J.Gourlay. I will try this out and let you know. Sorry for the in convenience due to lack of sufficient info in my question.